# Why Flask doesn't persists sessions with VueJS `npm run serve` frontend?

Tags: vue.js, session, flask, flask-restplus

I have a simple application with Flask and Rest-Plus on backend and VueJS frontend generated by `VueCLI 3`.

I am trying to set up sessions using Flask-Session but session variables saved in one request are not available in another.

I have tried lots of options but still got nothing.

Here is my `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        public: "localhost:8080",
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, x-id, Content-Length, X-Requested-With",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
        },
        proxy: {
            '/api*': {
                // Forward frontend dev server request for /api to django dev server
                target: 'http://localhost:5000/'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `app.py` I have set secret key and cors:

```
app.secret_key = "super_secret"
CORS(app, automatic_options=True, support_credentials=True)
```

Also, I have added decorators to my request handlers:

```
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def get(self):
```

And still nothing. In /login i set `session['aaa']=1` and in another request i got KeyError.

I run frontend via `npm run serve` and backend via `flask run`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding reverse proxy from flask. I've added it in my `app.py` so it passes all requests to frontend.

If you will use this solution while development, don't forget to remove this endpoint before deploying to production server.

```
@app.route('/dev', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/js/<path:dummy>', methods=['GET'])
def proxy(dummy=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        resp = requests.get(request.base_url.replace('5000', '8080'))
        excluded_headers = ['content-encoding', 'content-length', 'transfer-encoding', 'connection']
        headers = [(name, value) for (name, value) in resp.raw.headers.items() if name.lower() not in excluded_headers]
        response = Response(resp.content, resp.status_code, headers)
    return response
```